# Is a restricted airworthiness certificate required to operate a Cessna O-2A Skymaster in part 137 operations?

Tags: faa-regulations, aerial-application

Does a [Cessna Skymaster O-2A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_O-2_Skymaster) need to be classified as "restricted" if it is to dispense chemicals over a congested area, in a part 137 operation? The O-2A we're currently flying is classified as standard and the category is normal. It is a surplus army aircraft if that makes any difference.

Comment: Will you be doing low level application? Are the chemicals toxic? One needs to look at the operational and aircraft adaptations needed for the operation you are proposing.  So tell us more about your operation and the equipment, and you may get a better answer to your question.

Comment: Using economic poisons?  Also, normally 137 may not operate in congested areas. Is this where your land is?